# subdomain.domainname.com's server IP address could not be found

Tags: dns, cpanel

I have created a subdomain name alike domainname.com/subdomain.
And I placed my index page in the path: publichtml/subdomain/website.
It's perfectly working with the url- domainanme.com/subdomain/website But
But I also want it to open with the url- subdomain/domainname.com/website,
which showing the error "server IP address could not be found."

Answer (score 0):

edit the dns zone of your main domain from WHM >> edit DNS zone and add an A entry pointing to your subdomain